# Sorting an array breakdown

Tags: objective-c

I've been reading through a few different programs that use the sortUsingSelector method to sort an array with string objects and I can't figure out how they do it.

Each program begins by defining the sort method as follows:

```
[myBook sort];   /**myBook is the name of the array in the addressBook class**/ 

-(void) sort
{
    [book sortUsingSelector: @selector (compareNames:)];  
}
/**compareNames is defined in the addressCard class**/
```

The sort method uses a selector method that seems to do all the work:

```
-(NSComparisonResult) compareNames: (AddressCard *) element
{
    return [name compare: element.name];
}
```

Its important to note that there are two different classes: addressCard and addressBook.

I know the compare method returns NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, or NSOrderedDescending to the sortUsingSelector method.  But, how do these methods go about sorting everything?  I feel like I'm missing something huge.  For instance, how does the compare method know which elements in the array to compare?  I imagine that element[0] of the array is compared with element[1] and then a sort occurs then the next element is compared...Does the compare method have a default definition that I'm overlooking?

Comment: "Its important to note that there are two different classes: addressCard and addressBook". No. As far as the example is concerned, the only classes involved here are NSMutableArray and NSString. We are sorting an array of strings. Where the strings come from and where the array lives is immaterial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compare:` method (or any method you use as the parameter in `sortUsingSelector:`) just has one job: given exactly two objects (a pair), tell me how to order them. That is all it does.

It knows how to do this because it is defined by the class it is sent to. In this case, `name` is an NSString so we use NSString's definition of the `compare:` method - a definition that knows how to order strings (using rules about alphabetical order).

It is the `sortUsingSelector:` method that actually hands the `compare:` method pairs to, uh, compare. And how it chooses those pairs is its business. You are not told how it picks those pairs. Deciding what pairs to choose and in what order is a deep business; it is the subject of your Computer Science 101 class. But you are shielded deliberately from those details in this situation.

Comment: so `sortUsingSelector:` selects a pair of objects from the array and passes them to the `compare:` which returns NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, or NSOrderedDescending to `sortUsingSelector:` which then goes ahead and sorts accordingly?

Comment: Yes, except it obviously does that over and over and over until it has worked out the order of the whole array. The point is that the method specified as the selector only needs to know how to answer one tiny simple question: which of these two objects is "bigger", in whatever sense you interpret that? It is a helper function only. `sortUsingSelector:` is actually doing the sorting, and what algorithm it uses is unknown and immaterial.

Comment: So if the strings we have in our array consists of a first and last name and we want to sort them alphabetically by last name, we can create a customized compare method to compare the last names only?

Comment: Indeed. Here's an example of just that kind of thing: a custom compare method that sorts on the last character of the string. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/ch03p067functionPointer/ch03p067functionPointer/AppDelegate.m